# React is giving me a warnings after saving data to Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get the following warning whenever I add data to my firebase database how can I fix it?

> Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your
>   application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks
>   in the componentWillUnmount method.
>       in Groups (at App.js:62)

Code to save data to firebase on submit:

```
handleURLFormSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.toggleRewardModal();

    const self = this;
    let points = 0;
    const memberId = this.state.selectedMember;
    const groupID = this.state.groupid;
    const link = this.state.enteredURL;
    const postRef = database.ref("posts");
    const memberRef = database
        .ref("members")
        .child(memberId)
        .child("groups")
        .child(groupID);

    const groupRef = database
        .ref("groups")
        .child(groupID)
        .child("members")
        .child(memberId);

    memberRef
        .once("value", function(snapshot) {
            points = snapshot.val().points + 10;
        })
        .then(function() {
            memberRef.update({
                points: points
            });
            groupRef.update({
                points: points
            });
            postRef.push({
                link: link,
                member: memberId,
                group: groupID
            });

            self.getGroupMembers();
        });
};

componentWillUnmount() {
    database.ref("groups").off();
    database.ref("members").off();
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to unmount this component using logic from the parent?

Comment: how do i do that?